# How to optimize the spee view without overriding the views

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I am new to spree. I want to make some changes in the views of spree and for that i found two methods: 
1. Using Deface
2. By overriding the view

Currently, i am overriding the views but it was recommended that this approach is not very good. I want to use deface but unable to apply it:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path  => "spree/checkout/registration",
                     :insert_before => "div#registration",
                     :text          => "<p>Registration is the future!</p>",
                     :name          => "registration_future")
```

Please help me how could i optimize my views?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Deface` to replace content and insert new content by creating a ruby file with your code inside the `app/overrides` folder in your project.

```
/app
  /overrides
    future_registration.rb
```

The `future_registration.rb` will have the code you pasted. If you visit the url `spree/checkout/registration` after restarting the server, you should see the message in the page.